# Image alignment takes 100% of the paragraph

Tags: html, css, paragraph

I'm using tinyscrollbar plugin and I have a paragraph in which should be and image (aligned to the text). When I place it there it takes 100% of the width and 100% of the visible (I said I'm using scroll bar) height. How to fix it?

```
<div id="descriptionContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 60%; bottom: 20px; border: none; ">
    <div id="scrollbar1">
        <div class="scrollbar">
            <div class="track">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <div class="end"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="viewport">
            <div class="overview">
                <p> <img src="myImage.png" align="left" width="350" height="400" /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.... </p> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <img src="img/spacer.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
</div>
```

p tag css:

`p { text-align: justify; line-height: 1.5em; }`

.img class:

`.img { width: 25%; height: auto; background: none; }`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the relevant part of your code? Did you set a width and a height to the image?

Comment: `<div id="descriptionContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 60%; bottom: 20px; border: none; ">
<div id="scrollbar1">
<div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
<div class="viewport">
<div class="overview">
<p>
<img src="myImage.png" align="left" width="350" height="400" /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur....
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<img src="img/spacer.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
</div>`

Comment: What do you want it fixed to? You have explicitly set the only image to width 100% and likewise the height. Can you explain what you actual want it/expect it to be doing? Just noticed your comment. You should be able to edit the question to put that in there rather than having it in comments where it is harder to see and much much harder to read. :)

Comment: It's the main div with width: 100%; Look  at the IMG tag in .overview

Comment: Not the scope of the original question, but I wonder about using a "spacer.png" to begin with; images with that name are often used for hacks that could otherwise be solved with pure CSS. Again, though... more curious than anything since that's not your real question.

Comment: My real question is about the image myImage with width attribute 350 and height 400. DON'T PAY ANY ATTENTION TO THE SPACER. It's even not a css hack. It's a hack to detect mouseover on #descriptionContainer

Comment: The paragraph + image was missing in your first code post, I added it to your question (never add code in comments, always better to update your question). However, I don't see any reason why this image would take up 100% - there must be some code you're not sharing.

Comment: Thanks for updating my question :)
About the code I'm not sharing, maybe the css for the p tag. Anything else couldn't do any problems.

Comment: FIXED!
Just added a css class .img and classed the myImage image.

Thanks for the help, guys! :)

Answer (score 5):

Your image has width and height attributes on it:

```
 <img src="img/spacer.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Remove those and it will show up as it's natural size.

Comment: no, no, no.. The IMG tag with img src="myImage"  The spacer is just an IE fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="img/spacer.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

That is the line causing you problems, it will take all the space if possible. Try this:

```
<img src="img/spacer.png" />
```

Or this

```
<img src="img/spacer.png" width="[size]px" height="[size]px" />
```